# Difference sets of holomorphic injections

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $D$ be a bound domain in $\mathbb C$ and let $f$ and $g$ be injective holomorphic functions on $D$. Is it possible that the set $\{{w}:f(w) - g(w) = z\}$ is infinite for all but perhaps one complex numbers $z$?

Comment: In that case what about if you choose f and g to be linear polynomial with different leading coefficient then infact for every z you have only one solution, hence the set is finite for every z ?

Comment: Oh,I'm confused, I think you need example where f and g are injective having the above stated property.

Comment: The question is not whether the stated property holds for each pair of injective holomorphic maps, as that clearly is not the case. Instead what I am asking is if it holds for any,that is, if it is possible to find two holomorphic injections for which the difference sets are infinite for all but possibly one complex number.

Comment: Actually I have an idea to construct these functions, which I want to share with you. If we can construct two injective functions such that their difference is exponential map then may be we are done. So what I have in mind is to decompose the power series of exp in two power series in such a way that both the decoposed power series's define an injective holomorphic map. As it turns out that if our domain is complex plane we can not do that. See the problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427099/deleted-exponential-series-and-injectivity.

Comment: The next question is if we take our domain containing a vertical strip and it is not the complex plane and try to do the same as mentioned in the above comment. Note that in that way my domain is not bounded but we can map it biholomorphically to unit disc. So the question is to decopose the power series of exponential in two power series's such that they define injective map in the domain which is not the complex plane. So this is the auxiliary problem that I wanted to share with you. Please do comment if you have some idea on this. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you specify all but one value of $z$?  Is there some obvious obstacle to the set $\{w:f(w)-g(w)=z\}$ being infinite for all values of $z$?

Comment: Dear Trevor, I have no idea about your question any more than I have about mine, but the one potential exceptional value is there for analogy with the Big Picard theorem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but only some thoughts that I think could maybe help solve the problem. I will expand this post every time I have some new idea/result.

Let $D\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a bounded domain (i.e. open and connected), $A\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ any infinite subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Assume we have $f,g:D\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ two holomorphic functions such that for every $a\in A$ we have that $E_a:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}|f(z)-g(z)=a\}$ is infinite. Then since $D$ is bounded, and thus precompact, whe have that $E_a$ has an accumulation point $z_a$ in $\bar{D}$ (the closure of $D$). If $z_a\in D$, then by the [identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) we have that $f=g$, which is a contradiction. Thus $E_a$ must have an accumulation point on $\partial D$ for every $a\in A$.

I think that this can be useful in the search of a contradiction to the question, or in restricting the research for an example of two such functions. Personally, I propend to think that no two such functions exist.

Comment: I don't know why someone voted you down, I think this is an excellent observation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but too long to put as a comment.  I have an idea for creating an example of some such $f$ and $g$.

Consider the functions $f_1(x)=e^x(\cos(x)+10x)$ and $g_1(x)=e^x(\sin(x)+10x)$.  On $(0,\infty)$, these functions are injective (strictly increasing) and the set $\{x>0:f_1(x)-g_1(x)=r\}$ is infinite for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$.  Moreover, if we pre-compose with $\phi(x)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)$, then we can view $f_1$ and $g_1$ as having domain $(0,1)$, in which case the set $\{x\in(0,1):f_1(x)-g_1(x)=r\}$ is infinite for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$.

I don't know enough about the behavior of the trig functions to know whether this would extend nicely to the disk or not, but it is an idea.