# Deleted Exponential Series and Injectivity (2)?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a proper domain in $\mathbb{C}$ which contains a vertical line. If we consider the exponential map defined by the power series then it is not injective. I have the following question:

Let $\{n_ν:ν∈\mathbb{N}∖\{1\}\}$ be a strictly incresing sequence and delete those terms in exponential series with power indices coming from this set. Now consider the deleted series. When this defines an injective map in $\Omega$?

Remark.

1. Earlier I asked the same problem with $\Omega=\mathbb{C},$ see [Deleted Exponential Series and Injectivity (1)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427099/deleted-exponential-series-and-injectivity-1).
2. Note that the question is two fold with respect to the choice of domain and our sequence.